# Create a loop in a Java LinkedListArray and make the method detectLoop return true

Tags: java, linked-list

Am having a lot of trouble creating  node to complete a loop in this SinglyLinkedList after i checked whether it contains a loop with this method here `detectLoop`, The first call of this method returns an expected `false` because i created a SinglyLinkedList without a loop...So after printing out that boolean value, i tried to create a Node to loop the List but its still returning `false`, and then it says non-static member `Node` cannot be referenced from a `static` reference

```
class SinglyLinkedList {

    class Node {

        int data;
        Node next;

        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }
    //Represent the head and tail of the singly linked list    
    public Node head = null;
    public Node tail = null;

    //addNode() will add a new node to the list    
    public void addNode(int data) {
        //Create a new node    
        Node newNode = new Node(data);

        //Checks if the list is empty    
        if (head == null) {
            //If list is empty, both head and tail will point to new node    
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        } else {
            //newNode will be added after tail such that tail's next will point to newNode    
            tail.next = newNode;
            //newNode will become new tail of the list    
            tail = newNode;
        }
    }

    //display() will display all the nodes present in the list    
    public void display() {
        //Node current will point to head    
        Node current = head;

        if (head == null) {
            System.out.println("List is empty");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Nodes of singly linked list: ");
        while (current != null) {
            //Prints each node by incrementing pointer    
            System.out.print(current.data + " ");
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    //detectLoop method to check if the loop contains a loop and return boolean

    public boolean detectLoop() {
        Node fastPtr = head;
        Node slowPtr = head;
        while (fastPtr != null && fastPtr.next != null) {
            fastPtr = fastPtr.next.next;
            slowPtr = slowPtr.next;
            if (slowPtr == fastPtr) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SinglyLinkedList u = new SinglyLinkedList();

        u.addNode(7);
        u.addNode(6);
        u.addNode(4);
        u.display();
        //First Check return false as expected
        System.out.println("Does a loop exist in this linked list?" + " " + u.detectLoop());
        //Link a last noe to first node so that a loop is formed and check with method
        //This instantiation returns an error, please help
        Node loopNode = new Node(7);
        //The line above throws a non-static to static reference error so i cant create a loop
        u.display();
        System.out.println("Does it now contain a loop?" + u.detectLoop());
    }
}
```

Comment: if (slowPtr == fastPtr) this is likely your problem. before trying to work with complex structures, learn how to use the basics of Java. To check equality of values, use the equals method, not ==, which is a referential comparison.

Comment: I think my problem is trying to instantiate the non static Node internal class inside SinglyLinkedList in the main method

Comment: A) details matter. **and then it says non-static member Node** ...that is a **compiler error**. If you have a compiler ERROR you cant have executed your code. Because it does NOT compile. That compiler error is very common and with a bit of research you could have found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context ... specifically: you are using an **inner** class that is not static. You can NOT create an instance of Node WITHOUT having SingelyLinkedList instance!

Comment: After i instantiate a node then am gonna be able to loop members and form a loop

Comment: B) I disagree a bit with @Stultuske ... that really depends. Using == *might* be correct, but depends on your context.

Comment: I also think the same thing @GhostCat

Comment: So the first answer here is: either make Node a toplevel class, or make it static.

Comment: Okay am gonna try making it static, if that doesnt work am gonna move it out of SinglyLinkedList